# Silverlight datagrid export to excel with OOP design

Tags: c#, silverlight, oop, datagrid, export-to-excel

I am writting a small application that has some datagrids and I need to export that grids to MS Excel, it is working perfectly right now, however it is not a good OO design at all as I need to replicate my code for each datagrid instead of have a class capable to export to Excel, this is exactly my problem, I cant figure out how to create this class, right now for each datagrid export I have.

```
//Save dialog...create workbook... datashee, etc...
//Now.. fill the Excel with the datagrid info.
//To create the headers in a grid independent way I have
for (int i = 0; i < gridgui.Columns.Count; i  ) worksheet.Cells[0, i] = new Cell(gridgui.Columns[i].Header);

//My problem is... I dont know how to fill the content in a Source independent way, and I have fixed properties like this:
int renglon = 1;
foreach (dataStuff reg in infogrid) 
//dataStuff is my class that fills the ObservableCollection called infrogrid
{
    if (reg.Product != null)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[renglon, 0] = new Cell(reg.Product);
        worksheet.Cells[renglon, 1] = new Cell(reg.Price);
        renglon++;
    }
}
```

And this approach is working perfectly right now, however I know it is not the best way, my idea is to have a class that receives an ObservableCollection and a datagrid(to get Headers names. Optional?) and export it to excel like:

```
Exportme myexport = new Exportme(grid1,list1);
myexport.export();
Exportme myexport2 = new Exportme(grid2,list2);
myexport2.export();
```

Instead of using my current copy-paste technique :(

Thanks in advance.